# How to find (print) specified field in a Vector of Vector Java

Tags: java, function, vector, addition

We have to print the specified index of this vector but we aren't able to take the correct one.

After the creation of `SetA`, all the elements correspond to the last insertion, instead of the specified index.

Is there a way to add a `Vector` at the end of the preexisting vector?
In this way, the function "add" doesn't works!

```
    Vector <Vector <Integer>> setA = new Vector<Vector <Integer>>();
    Vector <Integer> temp = new Vector<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
        temp.clear();

        for(int j=0; j<=4;j++){
            temp.add(i*j);
        }                   
        setA.add(temp);
        System.out.printf("\nVector Temp: "+temp.toString());
        System.out.printf("\nElement i="+i+" of setA: "+setA.get(i).toString()+"\n");
    }
    System.out.printf("\nNow I want to print the vector that correspond index i=1 of set");
    System.out.printf("\n"+setA.get(1).toString()+"\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a Vector at the end of the preexisting vector > The `addAll` method does just that. And for the record, unless you are in a very specific multithreaded environment, you really should use ArrayList instead of Vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, you are trying to reuse same Temp again and again like:

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
    temp.clear();

    for(int j=0; j<=4;j++){
        temp.add(i*j);
    }                   
 setA.add(temp);
```

So when you start, you clear temp, add four elements and add same reference to vector setA. Now when you loop for the next time i.e. i=1, you remove all the elements from temp, so now your setA will contain an empty vector at location i =0;

So to avoid that, you should use:

```
 for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
    temp = new Vector<Integer>();//initialize every time. Do you really need Vector or list will work?

    for(int j=0; j<=4;j++){
        temp.add(i*j);
    }                   
    setA.add(temp);//do you  really need vector within vector?
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same reference to temp every time through the loop. You want to declare a new instance each time.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    Vector <Integer> temp = new Vector<Integer>();
    ...
}
```

Also, you should really use List/ArrayList as Vector is legacy.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I didn't remember that vector pass by reference.